# rosrun tf2_tools not found

Tags: ros, transform, tutorial, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the very [first tutorial of tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf2), we run the command `rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py`. I tried this on two different systems running Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic. On both systems, I get the error `[rospack] Error: package 'tf2_tools' not found`. I built my workspace using `catkin_make` and sourced my workspace. the ros master is running and I followed all tutorials exactly. `rospack find tf2_tools` yields the same error, but tf2 itself can be found. Any ideas why this is failing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263285/rosrun-tf2_tools-not-found/) by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2017-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to install `tf2_tools` if rospack can't find it.

`sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-tf2-tools`

If that's the issue we should add that as a dependency of tf2_turtle.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2017-06-06**:
That worked. I was using an underscore in `ros-$ROS_DISTRO-tf2-tools` (tf2_tools). It should probably be a dependency indeed.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-06-06**:
Glad that worked. I decided instead to just add it to the tutorial since the package itself doesn't need it really.